# Flutter Failed assertion: line 513 pos 14: 'file != null': is not true

Tags: flutter, dart

I have been trying to run a flutter app and it keeps giving me Failed assertion error. below is my code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart' as prefix0;
import 'package:image/image.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:simple_permissions/simple_permissions.dart';

import 'package:image/image.dart' as IO;



void main () async{
  await SimplePermissions.requestPermission(permissionFromString('Permission.WriteExternalStorage'));
  await SimplePermissions.requestPermission(permissionFromString('Permission.ReadExternalStorage'));
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: ImageDisplay(),));

}
Permission permissionFromString(String value){
  Permission permission;
  for (Permission item in Permission.values){

    if(item.toString()== value){
      permission =item;
    }
  }
  return permission;
}

class ImageDisplay extends StatelessWidget{

  File ReadFile (){
    IO.Image image = IO.readJpg(new File('/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/1575528198764.jpg').readAsBytesSync());
    try {
      IO.Image thumbnail = IO.copyCrop(image, 60, 60, 300, 200);
      //File('/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/${thumbnail}.jpg')
     // ..createSync(recursive: true)
     //   ..writeAsBytesSync(writeJpg(thumbnail));

      File img = new File('/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/1575528198764.jpg');
      return img;
    }catch (e){
      print(e);
    }



  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return new Scaffold(
      body:new Center(
        child: new SizedBox(child: prefix0.Image.file(ReadFile()),
        )

      ) ,
    );
  }
}
```

the Error has this line
'package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart': Failed assertion: line 513 pos 14: 'file !=
I/flutter (28465): null': is not true.

Comment: Somewhere you are feeding a null file to an image. This could be `Image.file` or `IO.copyCrop`. I'm inclined to guess that the file referenced in either place doesn't exist, but the `File` object itself could also be null. Without more information, I can't really speculate further.

Comment: Also on an unrelated note, get rid of `prefix0`. It's only there because you have a duplicate import, and it just makes the code confusing.

Answer (score 0):

```
child: new SizedBox(child: prefix0.Image.file(ReadFile()),
```

So in this line you're putting Image.file(ReadFile()) but the object that is returning is  ***null***.